# Magento2 Quickview Slider and Swatches Issue List Page

Tags: magento2, swatches, slider

I have added quick view on list page. But I could not load slider in image thumb in quick view also configurable options/swatches are not visible.

Does any one have faced this issue? Below is the screen shot for both the issues,

https://drive.google.com/file/d/0B1aJL9nhfbfFN1Q0RGR6cTNBaFk/view?usp=drivesdk
https://drive.google.com/file/d/0B1aJL9nhfbfFcDZvZERtTnZZZTQ/view?usp=drivesdk

Answer (score 1, accepted):

After debugging for a day I had find out below solution.

For Owl Crousel js issue i followed below steps for my module,
**Step1** : Added js below path,

```
Vendorname/Modulename/view/frontend/web/js/owl.carousel.js
```

**Step2**: In my custom file I have called js like this, where my files resides at below path,
Vendorname/Modulename/view/frontend/templates/product/myfile.phtml

```
<script type="text/javascript">

   require([
        //'cookiecode/jquery',
        'Vendorname_Modulename/js/owl.carousel',
    ], function () {
        jQuery(document).ready(function()
    {
        jQuery(".quick-view-thumb").owlCarousel({
                autoPlay: false, //Set AutoPlay to 3 seconds
                margin:4,
                items : 4,
                itemsDesktop : [1199,4],
                itemsDesktopSmall : [979,4],
                itemsTablet : [768,4],
                navigation : false,
                pagination : false
            });
    });
    });
</script>
```

With this successfully my js is now called in my custom page.

For swatch issue due to mismatch of block and function it was not working now successfully swatches are coming up in quick view too.

Problems have been fixed.